# in vim is it possible to skip the file explorer as last visited buffer?

Tags: vim

In vim, if I have several opened buffers, I can switch between the last and current one with the command `:b#`

It's visible if I show the list of buffers with `:ls` :

```
1  h "buffer 1" line 1
2 #h "buffer 2" line 1
3 %a "buffer 3" line 1
```

the `#` indicates the last buffer, and the `%` is the current one

but if I'm searching a file with the `:Explore` command, then if I use the alternate command `:b#` it will go back to the "Explored" buffer, but I would like to go back to the last buffer BEFORE the "Explored" buffer

of course it makes sense, but that's also very annoying ! It breaks the flow, and I wonder if there is a way to avoid that ? Especially since the explored window doesn't appear in the list of buffer, so it certainly has a special treatment ?

Comment: See `:help g:netrw_altfile`.

Comment: gg ! adding `let g:netrw_altfile = 1` in .vimrc worked perfectly :)

Comment: "I think `:Explore` is doing something special and I want to adjust that to solve my problem" --> "I pull up the doc of `:Explore` with `:help :Explore`" --> "I look around for options with `/options`" --> "The first hit is useless" --> "Hitting `n` *once* brings me to the promising `:help netrw-browser-options`" --> "I take a look at the list" --> "What I was looking for is literally the first item of the list" --> "I put it in my `vimrc` and I come back to what I was doing before". It takes what? Three minutes tops to find the answer without even a shred of previous knowledge of Netrw.

Comment: The issue is that everything becomes self-evident when you already know the answer. I don't know if OP made a reasonable effort, but it is not difficult to imagine one can miss an obvious answer by following the wrong line of investigation.

Comment: The process I added as a comment doesn't imply previous knowledge, though, that's the beauty of it. I didn't even know the answer myself and I found it in less time than it took me to read OP's question. No magic involved, no genius brain, no arcane commands or whatever. 12 years of vimming or 2 months? It makes no difference. Just a regular vimmer actually trying to solve a problem instead of pretending, deflecting, whining, and playing the victim card.

Comment: congratulations

Answer (score 0):

I post the solution to my own question

As mentioned by @romaini in the comments, `g:netrw_altfile` is a possible solution, see `:help g:netrw_altfile` : you just need to set the variable `let g:netrw_altfile = 1` in your .vimrc file

I quote from the vim help :

```
some like |CTRL-^| to return to the last
                   edited file.  Choose that by setting this
                   parameter to 1.
                   Others like |CTRL-^| to return to the
                   netrw browsing buffer.  Choose that by setting
                   this parameter to 0.
                   default: =0
```

where I learned also that you can hit `Ctrl-^` instead of typing `:b#`, cool

unfortunately this doesn't do exactly what I was looking for, since the "last
edited file" is actually the file that was marked as "alternate file" before opening the netrw buffer, in other world it's not the penultimate buffer, but the ante-penultimate one

However, another solution works well for me : using `:Lexplore` instead of `:Explore`, to open the netrw buffer in a new tab on the left

Doing this make the "alternate file" work as I expected : when opening the netrw buffer, the last current buffer (was marked with `%`) is made the alternate buffer (mark with `#`), and once a file is selected and opened from the netrw buffer, it opens in the right windows, replacing the last buffer and is marked as the current one (`%`)

The command `:b#` alternate with the last buffer before the netrw, as expected